# How can I add paragraphs to Woocommerce email text?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Currently the Woocommerce 'On Hold' email template specifies:

"Your order is on-hold until we confirm payment has been received. Your order details are shown below for your reference:"

I would like to change this to multiple paragraphs as follows:

"Thank you for your order, this is an automated response to advise that your order has made it safely into our hands.

Our order processing time is 2 days from payment of order.

Successful Paypal orders will be processed immediately."

Would someone be able to assist with advising what code I can use to replace this:

```
<p><?php _e( "Your order is on-hold until we confirm payment has been received. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Here is the full template code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer on-hold order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order is on-hold until we confirm payment has been received. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an echo for their own `<p> </p>` blocks:

```
<p><?php _e( "Thank you for your order, this is an automated response to advise that your order has made it safely into our hands.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<p><?php _e( "Our order processing time is 2 days from payment of order.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<p><?php _e( "Successful Paypal orders will be processed immediately.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```